# Event type property lost in IE-8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I've noticed a strange Javascript error which only seems to happen on Internet Explorer 8.  Basically, on IE-8 if you have an event handler function which captures the event object in a closure, the event "type" property seems to become invalidated from within the closure.

Here's a simple code snippet which reproduces the error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleClickEvent(ev)
            {
                ev = (ev || window.event);
                alert(ev.type);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    alert(ev.type); // Causes error on IE-8
                }, 20);
            }

            function foo()
            {
                var query = document.getElementById("query");
                query.onclick = handleClickEvent;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="query" type="submit" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            foo();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically, what happens here is that within the `handleClickEvent` function, we have the event object `ev`.  We call `alert(ev.type)` and we see the event type is "click".  So far, so good.  But then when we *capture* the event object in a closure, and then call `alert(ev.type)` again from within the closure, now all of a sudden Internet Explorer 8 errors, saying "Member not found" because of the expression `ev.type`.  It seems as though the `type` property of the event object is mysteriously gone after we capture the event object in a closure.

I tested this code snippet on Firefox, Safari and Chrome, and none of them report an error condition.  But in IE-8, the event object seems to become somehow invalidated after it's captured in the closure.

**Question**: Why is this happening in IE-8, and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this happens because the event data structure is a global variable in IE8 so it gets overwritten by other events when they happen.  If you need it to remain around for the closure, you will have to make an actual copy of the event data structure in the closure so you can reference the static copy rather than the one global structure that gets reused by IE8.

Making a copy of the data structure consists of making a new object and copying over all the properties.  If any properties themselves are objects or arrays, you have to make copies of them too (just assigning them to the new object will assign references, not copies).

Or, if you only need the `type`, then just assign the `type` to a local variable in the closure and just reference that like this.

```
function handleClickEvent(ev)
{
    ev = (ev || window.event);
    // save copy of type locally so we can use it later in setTimeout()
    var type = ev.type;
    alert(type);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert(type);
    }, 20);
}
```

Comment: +1, just would like to add that [doc-page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically mentions that... `The event object is available only during an event—that is, you can use it in event handlers but not in other code.`